# What *is* the coordinate ring K[V] of an algebraic variety V?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've been trying to understand this for a while.  If I understand it, we let V be an algebraic variety (set?) then define I(V) to be the ideal generated by V.  The coordinate ring is K[V] = K[X]/I(V), where K[X] is the polynomial ring of the underlying field K.

So, from my perspective, K[V] would be "the ring of all polynomials not in the ideal I(V)".  Is that correct?  If so:

1) Apparently, K[V] defines "the ring of all polynomials from V to K", but to me, that's a meaningless statement.  What does that even mean?  Is it true?

2) Why do I care about it?  For example, let's say I know what my variety V is and have fully parameterized it so that I can work with it "nicely".  Do I need to care about V anymore?

3) Does it in any way help me to define functions between two varieties? (this is what I'm trying to do, so hopefully...)

I am a bit confused about the concept, but it seems to be extremely important for further study...

Comment: Not "the ring of all polynomials not in the ideal", but "the ring of all polynomials ***modulo*** the ideal". The polynomials from $I(V)$ are zero on $V$, so, if we restrict our attention to $V$ and forget the whole surrounding space, the polynomials from $I(V)$ become identically zero, and they can be factored out to get $K[V]$ - the ring of polynomial functions on $V$.

Comment: More "up to" than "not in".

1) By dividing out $I(V)$, we do not distinguish any more between two polynomials that differ by a polynomial that vanishes on all of $V$. Thus we essentially consider our polynomaals *only* evaluated on $V$.

Comment: No, it is the ring of all polynomials *modulo* $I(V)$. So, $p(x), q(x) \in K[X]$ represent the same element in $K[V]$ iff they differ by an element of the ideal $I(V)$. Put another way, $K[X]$ is a ring of polynomials on $K$, and two polynomials $p(x), q(x)$ define the same element of $K(V)$ if they agree on $V$, that is, if their restrictions to $V$ are the same function.

Comment: As there are usually many parametrisations of the same variety, the specific parametrisation may simplify or complicate matters. In any case, it doesn't ship with the variety, whereas $K[V]$ does. Or, more formally, $K[\cdot]$ is a natural functor that maps varieties to rings. Geometric properties of the variety can be translated into algebraic properties of the coordinate ring. It is a beautiful piece of mathematics (which does not preclude that some ideas become clearer through parametrisations.)

Comment: So, moving into a far more concrete example, I have a variety and I actually know how to parameterize it in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a way that is useful to the underlying problem.  Would considering the coordinate ring provide me with anything more?  It doesn't really seem like it would.  Or, in other words, since I'm more interested in solving a particular problem *using* the variety, rather than "solving problems about varieties themselves", am I right to say that the concept is tangentially useful to me?

Comment: If $I(V)$ is generated by a simple equation the algebra of $K[V]$ may be much simpler than anything you can do with a parametrisation. So, yes, it can really help you to understand $V$.

Comment: I see.  Let's see if I have this small part right: I want a morphism between two varieties $Z_1(S_1)$ and $Z_2(S_2)$ defined on $X \subset A^n$ and $Y \subset A^m$, respectively.  This morphism is a function $f : x\in X \rightarrow y\in Y$.  This function must be composed of polynomials in $K(Z_1)$ only, because otherwise, if they are polynomials in $Z(S_1)$ itself, you'll only get zero anyway? I feel that I'm not making sense here

Comment: $K[Z_1]$ does not consist of polynomials, but of equivalence classes of polynomials (that are considered equal, if they are equal on $Z_1$, i.e. differ by an element of $I(Z_1)$.)  You may chose a representative of an equivalence class, i.e. one polynomial, but you can always add a polynomial in $I(Z_1)$. ...